# Reading https request from web-browser in C#

Tags: c#, sockets, https

I am developing a proxy in c# using socket programming. I got the success in reading the "http" request, however I am not able to identify the "https" request from browser. They appear to be 'GET' or 'POST' request. Is there any way to successfully get the "https" request from the web browser.

I used the following code to read the http request from web browser.

```
Socket m_socListener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream,     
   ProtocolType.Tcp);
IPHostEntry entry = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost");
System.Net.IPAddress ip = entry.AddressList[0];
IPEndPoint ipLocal = new IPEndPoint(ip, lisnPort);
m_socListener.Bind(ipLocal);
m_socListener.Listen(10);
Socket handle = m_socListener.Accept();

String data="";
String temp="";
int inforecv;                    
Byte[] receive=new Byte[1];
while (data.IndexOf("\r\n\r\n")==-1)
{
    inforecv = handle.Receive(receive);
    temp = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receive);
    data += temp;
}
```